# Return row number is match error

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have some tables in one sheet and I need to make a script to send an email everyday. The script it search today date, match it into my table and return column number, then I looks for Total on the first column (A) and once found it, return row number. Once I have row number and column number, return Total value for that day. I'm not advanced with JavaScript and I'm struggle with arrays (still learning). The script I have so far is working very good as long I have only one table on that sheet, but on the sheet will be over 50 tables, each one will have a Total at the end. The formula I have will find Total, but will return all Totals (row numbers) as Strings. What do I need is to get just the first Total (row number). I hope it all make sense.

I have attached an image to make an idea and my script I have so far:

```
function getTodaysTotal() {
 function toDateFormat(date) {
try {return date.setHours(0,0,0,0);}
catch(e) {return;}
}

var values = SpreadsheetApp
  .openById("ID")
  .getSheetByName("Q3 - W27 - 39")
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues();


for (i in values){
 if (values[i][0]=='Total'){
var nr = i;

   Logger.log(nr); // will return two values (41 - first total and 
   104 second total ... if you add more Total it will return all rows 
   numbers that contain word Total

 }
}

var today = toDateFormat(new Date());
var todaysColumn = 
values[5].map(toDateFormat).map(Number).indexOf(+today);
var output = values[nr][todaysColumn];
 //     Logger.log(output);
var emailDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today),"GMT+1", 
 "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

[image: table]

This is just the first table, but there will be more under this one and each one will have a Total.

Thank you!

Kind regards!

Comment: Can you provide an example sheet of your sheet with 50 tables, or better yet a link to the actual sheet?  What uniquely identifies each table from the others?

Comment: I can provide a test file with 2 tables. the pattern will be the same for all 50.      https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Of2qpfaz8Z8sAhblVP1ebllHR3WT7b3kEehli6xqe0U . ....

Comment: Thanks Andrei!  Would it be possible to get edit privileges to the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare nr outside of your loop since you will use the value.

```
var nr = 0;
```

Since you are reading an array, you should use the array length for you loop

```
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
  if (values[i][0]=='Total'){
    nr = i;
    Logger.log(nr); 
    break; // this will stop at the first match
  }
}
```

Once you get your total as a String, you can convert it to a number by calling the following function.

```
var string = values[a][b];
var num = Number(string);
```

Comment: Quick question ... what if I want the second value or the third one? I mean for the row only (Total). Thank you!