# Get second, third and so on values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446943/return-row-number-is-match-error)

The problem has been solved, but my question is how can I get the second value from that, or the third one. The sheet will have many tables and at some point I will need a total for each table. Also, is there any solution to automatically find the the array number which contain date row for each table (instead defining this manually). Hope my explanation make sense.

Thank you!

Kind regards,

L.E. [Test file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10pB0jDPG8HYolECQ3eg1lrOFjXQ6JRFwQ-llvdE2yuM)

Comment: Your question would be much easier to understand if I could look at your spreadsheet.  It's very difficult to see any detail on the image.

Comment: I have added a test file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, instead of breaking the loop when a match to "Total" is found do whatever is needed to be done within the loop like so...

```
var today = toDateFormat(new Date());
var todaysColumn = 
    values[5].map(toDateFormat).map(Number).indexOf(+today);
var emailDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today),"GMT+1", 
                                     "dd/MM/yyyy");
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
  if (values[i][0]=='Total'){
    nr = i;
    Logger.log(nr); 

    var output = values[nr][todaysColumn];
    //     Do something with the output here I"m assuming you email it

  }
}
```

The loop will keep going and find every "Total" and do the same thing.  This answer assumes that the "Totals" are in the same column.  You can get fancier with this if you only want certain tables to send and not others, but this should get you started.

I didn't quite understand the second part of your question...

> "Also, is there any solution to automatically find the the array
>   number which contain date row for each table (instead defining this
>   manually). Hope my explanation make sense."

I'm guessing you want all the rows that contain "Total" in the specific column.  You could instantiate a variable as an empty array like so, `var totals = [];`.  Then instead of sending the email or whatever in the first loop you would push the row values to the array like so, `totals.push(nr+1) . //adding 1 gives you the actual row number (rows count from 1 but arrays count from 0)`.  You could then simply loop through the totals array and do whatever you wanted to do.  Alternatively you could create an array of all the values instead of row numbers like `totals.push(values[nr][todaysColumn])` and loop through that array.  Lots of ways to solve this problem!

---

### **Ok based on our conversation below I've edited the "test" sheet and updated the code. Below are my edits**

All edits have been made in your test sheet and verified working in Logger.  Let me know if you have any questions.

**Spreadsheet:**

1. Added "Validation" Tab
2. Edited "Table" tab so the row with "Email Address" in Column A lines up with the desired lookup values (dates or categories)...this was only for the first two tables as all the others already had this criteria.

**Code:**
Create table/category selector...

1. In the editor go to File >> New >> HTMLfile
2. Name the file "inputHTML"
3. Copy and paste the following code into that file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <base target="_top">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form class="notice_form" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="formSubmit(this)" target="hidden_iframe">
         <select id="tables" onchange="hideunhideCatagory(this.value)" required></select>
         <p></p>
         <select id="categories" style="display:none"></select>
         <hr/>
         <button class="submit" type="submit">Get Total</button>
      </form>
      <script>
         window.addEventListener('load', function() {
         console.log('Page is loaded');
         });
      </script>
      <script
         src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         // The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
         $(function() {
         var tableRunner = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTableList);
         var catagoryRunner = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildCatagoryList);
           
           tableRunner.getTables();
           catagoryRunner.getCategories();
         });
         
         function buildTableList(tables) {
         var list = $('#tables');
         list.empty();
         list.append('<option></option>');
         for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
         if(tables[i]==''){break;}
         list.append('<option>' + tables[i] + '</option>');
         }
         }
         
         function buildCatagoryList(categories) {
         var list = $('#categories');
         list.empty();
         list.append('<option></option>');
         for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
         if(categories[i]==''){break;}
         list.append('<option>' + categories[i] + '</option>');
         }
         }
         
         function hideunhideCatagory(tableValue){
         var catElem = document.getElementById("categories");
         if(tableValue == "Total Calls By Date" || tableValue == "Total Appointments by Date"){
         catElem.style.display = "none"
         document.required = false;
         }else{
         catElem.style.display = "block"
         document.required = true;
         }
         
         }
         
         function formSubmit(argTheFormElement) {
         
         var table = $("select[id=tables]").val(),
           catagory = $("select[id=categories]").val();
         console.log(table)
         google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
         .getTotal(table,catagory);
         }
      </script>
   </body>
   <div id="hiframe" style="display:block; visibility:hidden; float:right"> 
      <iframe name="hidden_iframe" height="0px" width="0px" ></iframe>
   </div>
</html>
```

**Edits to Code.gs file**
Replace code in Code.gs with this...

```
//This is a simple trigger that creates the menu item in your sheet
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Run Scripts Manually')
  .addItem('Get Total','fncOpenMyDialog')
  .addToUi();

}
//This function launches the dialog and is launched by the menu item
function fncOpenMyDialog() {
  //Open a dialog
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('inputHTML')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Select table to get total for');
};


//main function called by clicking "Get Total" on the dialogue...variables are passed to this function from the formSubmit in the inputHTML javascript
function getTotal(table,catagory) {
  function toDateFormat(date) {
    try {return date.setHours(0,0,0,0);}
    catch(e) {return;}
  }

  //get all values
  var values = SpreadsheetApp
  .openById("10pB0jDPG8HYolECQ3eg1lrOFjXQ6JRFwQ-llvdE2yuM")
  .getSheetByName("Tables")
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues();

  //declare/instantiate your variables
  var tableHeaderRow, totalRow, tableFound = false;
  //begin loop through column A in Tables Sheet
  for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
    //test to see if values have already been found if so break the loop
    if(tableFound == true){break;}
    //check to see if value matches selected table
    if (values[i][0]==table){
      //start another loop immediately after the match row
      for(var x=i+1; x<values.length; x++){
        if(values[x][0] == "Email Address"){ //This header needs to consistantly denote the row that contains the headers
          tableHeaderRow = x;
          tableFound = true;
        }else if(values[x][0] == "Total"){
          totalRow = x;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log("Header Row = "+tableHeaderRow)
  Logger.log("Total Row = "+ totalRow)
  var today = toDateFormat(new Date())
  var columnToTotal;
  if(catagory==''){
    columnToTotal = values[tableHeaderRow].map(toDateFormat).map(Number).indexOf(+today);
  }else{
    columnToTotal = values[tableHeaderRow].indexOf(catagory);
  }

  var output = values[totalRow][columnToTotal];
  Logger.log(output);
  var emailDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today),"GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");

  //here is where you would put your code to do something with the output

}

/** The functions below are used by the form to populate the selects **/
function getTables(){
  var cFile = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cSheet = cFile.getSheetByName('Validation');
  var cSheetHeader = cSheet.getRange(1,1,cSheet.getLastRow(),cSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().shift();
  var tabelCol = (cSheetHeader.indexOf("Tables")+1);
  var tables = cSheet.getRange(2,tabelCol,cSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  return tables.filter(function (elem){
    return elem != "";
  });
}

function getCatagories(){
  var cFile = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cSheet = cFile.getSheetByName('Validation');
  var cSheetHeader = cSheet.getRange(1,1,cSheet.getLastRow(),cSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().shift();
  var catagoriesCol = (cSheetHeader.indexOf("Catagory")+1);
  var catagories = cSheet.getRange(2,catagoriesCol,cSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  return catagories.filter(function (elem){
    return elem != "";
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already had this done. This problem was solved in the link I provided, but if you can have a look at the file I have updated in my comment would be much easier to understand. I need a loop to find all Totals and then return first Total (row number) when I call it (this was solved using break), then I need second total when I call it and so on ....

Comment: Also, var todaysColumn = 
    values[5].map(toDateFormat).map(Number).indexOf(+today); ... this is for the second part. As you can see, I have todaysColumn which contains dates. For the first table (look at the file), this will be a fixed value, but I will have more tables and in time I might add some new emails and I need something to find the row with the date for the second (maybe third) table later ... hope make sense.... Thank you!

Comment: I think this makes sense, and should be doable.  You have tables (Total Calls By Date, Total Appointments By Date, Overall, Client 1 etc..) and you wish to get totals for specific items from specific tables and different times and email them?  I'll have a look...could you please load your existing code into the test file.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated.  Would you be willing to indicate the exact way the code is run?  Trigger (onchange or timed), menu item etc...  Also How do you determine whether it's the first or other table to get and send the total from.  Additionally, I noticed that only the first two tables have dates the rest (client 1, client 2 etc...) have items.  Is this a typical format...do you every need to mine a total from these?  Would a functionality of selecting which table you wish to get the total from be helpful?

Comment: I would like to get total from all tables and totals by current date from tables with date rows. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Andrei, so for the client/overall columns you want the total for each of the types (Calls Bookings Conversions Booked Appointments Cancelled Appointments Declined Appointments)?  Also will you always want all the totals on all the tables or only specific ones at specific times?

Comment: Just on request ... there will be a button or sub-menu ... thank you !!!

Comment: Ok...check out rest as well as my edits above and let me know what you think.  If his works for you please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Andrei, I discovered an issue with parts of the code and am in in the midst of trouble shooting...

Comment: Ok got everything working...I made a slight alteration for the test that displays the value in the popup when you select the item to get a total form.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look now!

Comment: is there any chance to get exactly the same result without using HTML form? To have all Totals rows (index number) in an array and call it based on client  or store them in variables? Thank you!

Comment: You could probably code a script to executive on a timed trigger that gathers all the information based on your predefined list of criteria into a JSON object then pull that information using an in-cell dropdown in conjunction with an onedit trigger.